# Search questions without comments

Tags: support, comments, search, unanswered-questions

I was wondering if it is also possible to search for questions which are unanswered AND also lack any comments? I could not find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) or using Google.

Comment: Is there a reason to want to do this? The network deliberately view comments as 'expendable' so they are not generally part of searching ...

Comment: @JosephWright If you want to find unanswered questions, which are not resolved in the comments.

Comment: Not all questions that have comments but no answers are automatically answered by the comments. Some are, true. You can browse all unanswered questions, have a look at the comments (if any) and ping the user who gave the answer or even flag as duplicate or unclear. It is a bit more work, but it is much more helpful in the long run. My opinion at least.

Comment: @Johannes_B That is true. Although I find that when I look through those questions, I come across quite a few which were answered in the comments and I did not want to make community wiki answers for them all.

Comment: @Roald Pinging the user who answered is definitely not writing a CW answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only link the two databases containing `posts` and `comments` using the [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com). [The following query](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/548225/positive-scoring-unanswered-questions-that-are-not-closed-and-without-comments) lists questions on the main site, sorted by their last activity date (oldest to newest) with these attributes:

- No comment
- No answer
- Not closed
- Positive score

```
select top 1000
    p.id as [Post Link],
    p.lastactivitydate as [Last Active]
from posts p
left outer join comments c on c.postid = p.id
where p.posttypeid = 1 -- Questions
and c.id is null
and answercount = 0 
and p.score > 0
and closeddate is null
order by lastactivitydate
```